# Can you export a conda env without environment variables?

Tags: python, environment-variables, conda

Conda 4.9 added the ability to set and export environment variables in a yml file as seen in the docs: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables

However, there are times I want to export an environment.yml file and keep the environment variables hidden since the yml file will be in a public repo. Do the variables just need to be manually removed from the yml file every time, or is there a flag I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [`conda env export`](https://veranostech.github.io/docs-korean-conda-docs/docs/build/html/commands/env/conda-env-export.html) says there are no flags to exclude environmental variables. But you can use

> --no-builds
> Remove build specification from dependencies

> --ignore-channels
> Do not include channel names with package names.

Comment: It appears manually removing environmental variables is the only method then. Seems to be a major oversight unless I'm misunderstanding how most people use them